# Shape Key decimate modifier

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I am trying to morph a high poly humanoid into a low poly humanoid, animating the decimation. As far as I know this cannot be done with the Decimate Modifier. I have also tried doing this by using shape keys and applying 'limited dissolve' while in edit mode, without success.

Would anyone know a work around to create a high to low poly animation?

Thanks!

Comment: Would baking the high poly to a texture map to use on low poly model, then animate the influence, be an option?  Can I suggest too, changing to title of q to something like "How to create a high to low poly animation?"

Comment: The answer depends on your setup and precise goal. Do you wan to morph between 2 specific objects or do you simply want to lower the number of polygons randomly ? If you have specific objects, is the high poly version just a subdivided version or is it completely different (like a dyntopo sculpt) ?

Answer (score 2):

Shape keys in blender allows you to translate and  scale different vertices, edges and faces of a mesh. Even though Shape keys changes the structure/geometry of a mesh, they always maintain the same number of polygons.

So any changes involving changes in poly count usually won't work well for Shape Keys. So for this situation, Shape Keys cannot be used.

However,you could try animating the iterations/ratio/angle limit of the decimate modifier. Just press i on a slider and the slider turns yellow which means the slider is Keyframed.

Comment: Shape keys don't rotate vertices, they only translate them. If you add a shape key and rotate your object, the object will deform in the in-between values. (with a 180° rotation it will become a single line at 0.5)

Comment: In a shape key I guess  faces and edges be rotated, right?

Comment: This is a shapekey with a 180° rotation, you can see each vertex is only translating :
http://i.imgur.com/2NupAYU.gifv

Comment: OK I got it I removed the term 'rotation' from my answer. Did I make any other mistake?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.